# Flush() from JSON.NET does not work as expected

Tags: java, c#, android, json, .net-core

I write server in .NET Core based on server which was written in Java. In .net core I have:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(OutputStream);
writer.WriteStartArray();
serializer.Serialize(writer, result); //result = [{ "Success": true}
writer.Flush(); //Java client received message and generate error: Incomplete document
```

In java, server code looks like:

```
Json Writer writer = new JsonWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8")));
writer.beginArray();
Result result = new Result();
gson.toJson(result, Result.class, writer);
writer.flush(); //Java client still waiting
```

and Java client where error is generated:

```
jsonReader.beginArray();
result = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Result.class);
```

In Java, everything works, but in .net core not. I've checked packets by Wireshark and everything was sent. And when I debug client I have an error: `"Incomplete document", java.io.IOException: Incomplete document"`. What can be wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to call writer.WriteEndArray() ?

Comment: @PalleDue Yes and in both code are this line, but after writer.flush. Even if I wrote this before, debugger through me the same error: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was hard to find. But whole yesterday I spent with debugger and I found a problem. In java client I looked what is in 'result' and 'jsonReader':

```
result = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Result.class);
```

and I figured out that jsonReader's buffer looks like [{ "Success": true}
and result's buffer like [{ "success": false} after execute the line. And why? Because model Result has field call 'success', not 'Success' in Java. And to .net core Result class I just added

```
[JsonProperty("success")]
```

and problem disappeared :) maybe it helps someone one day.

Comment: Look at JsonSerializerSettings, you can configure it to automatically camelCase properties.